# Can backbone.js run on apache?

Tags: apache, backbone.js

Any good references on how to set it up on apache if possible? Is it not recommended?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BackboneJS doesn't require any server setup it's a library for javascript and since javascript isn't a server-side language I don't understand why you ask this... Apache has nothing to do with backboneJS, you just need to include the backbone.js in your html. For more information [read the documentation](http://backbonejs.org) and take a look at the [example app](http://backbonejs.org/docs/todos.html).